# Cannot tag a question using the Android app and therefore cannot post a question

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I've been trying to use the app, but I'm really disappointed. It's a good anti frustration and patience practice. But I'm sorry to say, it's not been a good app experience.

I've lost a lot of questions, because they keep getting deleted. When trying to add tags, it's just not working. No tags shows up and I can't post without tags.

What is wrong? Something I can do - other than uninstalling it?

Comment: When i'm navigating this site from my phone, i just do so from the browser on my phone instead of my app; works just fine. not sure if this is an option for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you're having trouble with it.

I changed this topic's tag from [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) to [support](/questions/tagged/support). It's possible  but uncertain whether someone knowledgeable will reply (I'm not knowledgeable:I didn't know there was an app, I only use a browser).

There is another web site, [meta.stackexchange.com](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/) (this site, `meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com`, is mostly for questions about the content of `buddhism.stackexchange.com`, and questions about the StackExchange software which we can answer ... whereas `meta.stackexchange.com` is for problem reports about the StackExchange software, and issues that aren't specific to any single site).

In summary you might find an answer if you read or post a question on `meta.stackexchange.com`.

You didn't mention what kind of app you're using but [Posts containing 'app'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=app) there show that site has topics with [android-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app) and [ios-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios-app) tags.

I'd search on meta to see if there's an existing post that's like the problem you're reporting using a search like https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bios-app%5D+tag however I don't quite know what I'm looking for.

For example your problem might be [similar to this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264425/139866) or perhaps there are others like that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is mainly on the phone I have prblems. The tags are the biggest issue I guess, as I can't post without tags.

Answer (score 1):

As we are still not getting enough question (10 per day) is it possible for some one to investigate and undeleted these accidentally deleted questions.

Comment: I think you can see recently-deleted posts (answers and questions) here: http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/tools ... from the description I'd guess that the questions weren't "deleted" as such, instead they were never posted to the site (by the app), and also never saved on the OP's device.

Comment: I'd like to add that I really like the site and all you do both on the tech side and otherwise. Because of my job I use the phone/APP, because regular web is a bit small there. Hope it will work out - )