# Functionalities on APP and APP tag

Tags: support

Are there any functionalities in the APP apart from plain writing and cut/paste? Is there no toolbar, I cant seem to find one. And how about HTML/link and the simple > _ and ** tags, do they function in the APP?

It also seems that when I use the APP on the Android phone, it don't allow tagging which is a condition for posting the question. That makes it a bit difficult. Am I the only one experiencing these challenges?

Should there be a tag called app or functionalities APP (probably not good English, but you get the point)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no-one on this site seems to know enough about the app to be able to answer questions about it.

See also [this answer](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1798/254).

I suggest you ask on the main meta.stackexchange.com site instead. It's quite a busy site, I apologise in advance if any answers there are brusque ... let me know if you need extra help with posting there.

There is an [android-app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-app) tag on that site.

---

FYI, though I use the regular desktop browser, I never use the toolbar ... I type in `**` and `>` and `[]()` and so on by hand, using the keyboard. Those [markdown characters](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) are interpreted by the server, not on the client side, so it doesn't matter how (keyboard or toolbar) you get them into the post.

Comment: Thanks. I'll put on my armor of concepts (Mr. Concept's Iron Shirt) and dive in!